# Does Mathematica have this function implemented?

Tags: expression-manipulation, piecewise

Is there a function in *Mathematica* that can express a piecewise function in terms of the Heaviside theta function? Say, for example, the solution to this [ODE](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%20%2B%20y%27%20%2B%205%2F4%20y%20%3D%20Piecewise%5B%7B%7Bsin%20(t),%200%20%3C%20t%20%3C%20pi%7D,%20%7B0,%20t%20%3E%3D%20pi%7D%7D%5D,%20y(0)%20%3D%200,%20y%27(0)%20%3D%200).

Comment: There is an internal, undocumented function ``Simplify`PWToUnitStep`` that you can use.

Comment: ...and then you can replace all instances of `UnitStep[]` with `HeavisideTheta[]` if need be. Tho, I need to give this reminder again, I think: use `UnitStep[]` for numerics, and `HeavisideTheta[]` for symbolics.

Comment: What’s the reason for using `HeavisideTheta` rather than `UnitStep` for symbolics? Is this advice is still relevant in newer versions? And why do `FourierTransform[HeavisideTheta[x] BesselJ[1, x], x, t]` and some other transforms return results in terms of `UnitStep` functions rather than `HeavisideTheta` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to take the `LaplaceTransform` and then invert it back. `InverseLaplaceTransform` uses `HeavisideTheta` automatically.

This might not be the most efficient method, and might not always work.

```
ClearAll[y,t];
ode=y''[t]+y'[t]+5/4*y[t]==Piecewise[{{Sin[t],0<t<Pi},{0,t>=Pi}}];
ic={y[0]==0,y'[0]==0};
sol=y[t]/.First@DSolve[{ode,ic},y[t],t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[sol,{t,0,20},PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now ship it to Laplace and get it back

```
lap=LaplaceTransform[sol,t,s];
sol=FullSimplify[InverseLaplaceTransform[lap,s,t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[sol,{t,0,20},PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]